# Loading buffer in image, reflected as blob null

Tags: javascript

I'd a server that is loading an image in the web using a template as:

```html
<body><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{.Image}}"></body>`
```

Where `{{.Image}}` is a buffer data.

I'm trying to collect this buffer through a client, JavaScript only, using `fetch` and add it to the `<img>` element, so I wrote the below:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img id="photo" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const myRequest = new Request('http://localhost:8080/blue/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers(),
        type: "arraybuffer",
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default',
        });

        fetch(myRequest)
            .then(response => {
                var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(response);
                var blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], {type: "image/jpeg"});
                return blob})
            .then(myBlob => {
                var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(myBlob);
             //   var imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
                var img = document.querySelector("#photo");
                img.src = imageUrl;
            });
    </script>
</html>
```

While loading the page, I got the `img` element content to be:

```html
<img id="photo" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600" src="blob:null/c94ac446-55c5-4ee5-a492-5286b1935ffb">
```

And nothing displayed.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it as below:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <img id="photo" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const myRequest = new Request('http://localhost:8080/blue/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: new Headers(),
        type: "arraybuffer",
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default',
        });

        fetch(myRequest)
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
                reader.onloadend = function() {
                    var imageUrl = reader.result;                
                    var img = document.querySelector("#photo");
                    img.src = imageUrl;
                }
            });
    </script>
</html>
```